# Кодировка на сайте

Tags: php, html, mysql, кодировка

Здравствуйте.

Залил сайт на новый хостинг, а там проблема с кодировкой.

Нормально отображает, если текст в таком формате: `РќРµ СѓРґР°Р»РѕСЃСЊ РІС‹Р±СЂР°С‚СЊ Р‘Р”!`. На странице сделал кодировку UTF-8, вроде нормально, но когда вывожу из БД, то он тоже принимает только в таком формате, а если текст нормальный (русскими буквами), то он выводит это [image]. В базе стоит кодировка `utf8_unicode_ci`

[image: phpinfo() mysql]

Comment: Выполните все [перечисленные пункты](http://hashcode.ru/questions/386724/html-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=386787#386787).

Comment: Помогло, но при добавление в бд добавляем иероглифы.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://hashcode.ru/questions/387332/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B4?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=387335#387335)

Comment: @romeo ничего не помогает. Не подскажите хороший хостинг с тестовым периодом и по цене недорогой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте через [PDO](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/), а не через процедуры

```
$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8;', 'user','pass');
$pdo->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$stm = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name FROM table');
$stm->execute();
$stm->fetchAll();
```

По хостингу. Если есть навыки настройки, то лучше облако: [vdsina (в рублях)](http://vdsina.ru/), [DO (в валюте, через paypal)](https://www.digitalocean.com/) - [инструкция по оплате](http://digitalocean.su/registr)

Из shared-хостингов: [timeweb](http://timeweb.com/ru/services/hosting/).